# Check for overlapping time ranges - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have an array of time slots

```
[
      {
        startTime: "13:00",
        endTime: "15:00"
      },
      {
        startTime: "17:00",
        endTime: "20:00"
      }
]
```

and I have a time slot from the user -

```
const timeSlot = {
  startTime: '16:00',
  endTime: '18:00'
}
```

I want to check if there's any collision/overlapping of time slots before adding it to the array. What is the most optimal way to do this?

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with some conditions (if len is 0 add it)

Comment: What are your criteria for "most optimal"? What have you tried? In what regard is it sub–optimal?

Comment: @RObG My criteria for optimal is to reduce the number of comparisons. Say for the method below by Viktur, we are comparing every item (O(n)). I was wondering if we could sort the times and apply O(log(n)) in some way?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```js
// assuming this is sorted
const times = [
  {
    startTime: "13:00",
    endTime: "15:00"
  },
  {
    startTime: "17:00",
    endTime: "20:00"
  }
];

// given timeSlot by the user
const timeSlot = {
  startTime: '16:00',
  endTime: '18:00'
}

// function to transform the given time to the minutes of a day
const toMin = (time) => {
    const [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');
    return Number(hours) * 60 + Number(minutes);
};

// find the index of the time where the given time could be inserted
const indexToInsert = times.findIndex(({ endTime }) => toMin(endTime) <= toMin(timeSlot.startTime)) + 1;

// check wether the next startTime allows adding the given timeSlot
const isValid = !times[indexToInsert] || toMin(times[indexToInsert].startTime) >= toMin(timeSlot.endTime);

console.log(isValid)
```

Comment: @RobG I've removed that dependency. Thanks for pointing this out as I keep forgetting that Date parsing is still problematic across different browsers.

Comment: Could you please add comments to your code, so that it's more understandable?

Comment: @vaibhavdeep Added some comments